# How does webpack Plugin modify the image resource address used in JS Assets

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-4

I want to implement a WebPack4 plugin that can upload certain files to the CDN after packaging, such as images

However, I found that the image address loaded in assets JS in the **compiler.hooks.emit** phase was written dead. I cannot update it. The current address after packaging is as follows:

```
cf05:function(e,t,n){e.exports=n.p+"img/logo.82b9c7a5.png"}}
```

I would like to update this image address to the following,

```
https://www.test.com/cdn/img/logo.82b9c7a5.png
```

I can't use PublicPath because it's for all resources, I want it to be for some resources, is there an API that can do that

Thank you very much